# Can't deploy ruby application

Tags: ruby, apache

I'm trying to get [this ruby application](https://github.com/phstc/putsmail) working on my server but I have very little Ruby knowledge and I am hitting a wall right now.

The unit tests described behind the "build passing" button at the bottom of the git page are all succeeding on my machine so I think I shouldn't be too far from the solution, but all that I can get from the app is this 404 page : http://projects.uselessworks.com/

here is the configuration of my virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName projects.uselessworks.com

    DocumentRoot /var/vhosts/dev/putsmail/public
    RailsEnv production
    RailsBaseURI /

    <Directory /var/vhosts/dev/putsmail/public>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            RailsBaseURI /
            PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The application is located into /var/vhosts/dev/putsmail/, and i basically followed the steps of the unit tests to install it.

Can someone give me some advice on what could go wrong here ?

Edit :

I have this line occuring for each connection attempt in my error.log :

```
[ 2013-09-28 14:10:50.2478 30766/7fe000fe0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 30804 stderr] cache: [GET /] miss
```

this is the only thing that seems relevant here.

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your log file? (It appears to be /var/log/apache2/error.log)

Comment: I edited my question with the content of the log.

Comment: The error line you posted appears to be truncated?

Comment: I just checked and there is no error here, this is the full line as it appears in the log

Comment: Did you solve this? getting the same thing... every access.log gets written with this gobbledygook in error.log after.